# How to set up Logwatch to receive high level messages immediately?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, logwatch

I have set up Logwatch on my (Debian) system. Mailing etc works well.

What I would like to is to get a daily report of the system once a day

And;

To receive any high level (failed login attempts, attacks -if possible- etc) immediately as they happen.

Which settings do I need to modify and modify with what exactly? I am quite a newbie when it comes to working with systems and I did my research on Google but the results only lead me thus far.

Thank you.

Comment: Agreed with Michael below. You're trying to use the wrong tool. Logwatch is a batch processing system, designed to be run occasionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LogWatch runs once per day, from cron -- If you want more frequent notifications you can run LogWatch more frequently, but that this will send you *everything* that LogWatch normally complains about.

If you want to watch for specific messages you should be using something more sophisticated than LogWatch (`syslog-ng` with custom filters/actions springs immediately to mind, particularly if you want "immediate" notifications), or writing your own tool to scan the log files on a tighter schedule.

---

#### Be Careful What You Wish For

Asking your system to send you emails for every "important" event can quickly become overwhelming.  For example there are over 1000 failed login attempts on my personal system ***TODAY*** (in the past 11 hours) -- I certainly don't want to be emailed for each one of those: I have enough spam.

Proper monitoring and alerting should only be telling you about things that require action on your part (LogWatch in my experience is *awful* at that, to the point where I've completely disabled it in my environment because it's just creating noise) -- Make sure whatever system you implement has a very low noise level so you don't fall into the all-too-common trap of ignoring alerts because "I see that all the time and it's never important".

Comment: Thank you voretaq. Could you please advise on which exact watching tools do you use and what settings do you have? (what do you think is worthy of getting notified about).

Comment: I generally don't monitor system logs - instead I use performance based monitoring (response time, resource utilization, hardware issues (dead disk, etc.)), operational status notification (up/down/degraded/unexpected-response) and a basic IDS (Snort) to tell me if something "interesting" is going on on the network.  In my environment logs are only for debugging a problem that the monitoring system has alerted us to (or one it didn't catch).

Comment: And what are your preferences in regards for the tools used to perform these tasks?

Comment: @Phil Take your pick - the right tool is the one that meets your requirements. I user Intermapper, lots of people use Nagios, or Opsview, or OpenNMS...

Comment: @Phil If you poke around in the [tag:monitoring] tag on this site you'll find lots of other options/opinions

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using rsyslog, which is the default on Debian squeeze:

Use [rsyslog's mail output module](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ommail.html) to send yourself email. You can configure which messages get sent to you in the usual way:

```
*.emerg  :ommail:;mailBody
```

or by matching text in the log message:

```
if $msg contains 'hard disk fatal failure' then :ommail:;mailBody
```